# How to create a form level Initvalue in ax 2012?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

In ax 2012 i have created and worked with various table level methods like initvalue,validatewrite etc but if i want to create a init() method in form level how should i proceed with coding section after clicking override method as initvalue in data source level.And also please send me some good books,website link for working in formlevel methods (data source, design and control levels).
Thank you in advance

Varun .G

Answer (score 0):

On your form, go to the `Data Sources` node. Expand it, locate the data source on which you want to overwrite the `initValue` method of, and expand that. You can then right click the `Methods` node and overwite the `initValue` method.

Also check these references on MSDN:

- [Methods on a Form [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa674599.aspx)
- [Methods on a Form Data Source [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893931.aspx)